# migrar base de datos access a sql server

Tags: sql

Tengo dos bases de datos en access con extensión .401 y .402, las quiero importar a SQL server. Ya probé guardándolas como extensión .mdb y .accdb, y no consigo pasar todas las tablas a sql, solamente se importan la mitad, el resto no tengo que volver hacer el proceso y el sistema que se conecta a la base de sql empieza a arrojar errores de conexión.

Me pueden ayudar por favor, Gracias.

Algo estaré omitiendo.

Comment: Bienvenido para que sea bien recibida tu pregunta es **importante leer [ask]**

Comment: que extension rara. como las estas importando? mira por favor [tour] y [ask]